# existing element's style not change via js

Tags: javascript, laravel

I want to change an elements visibility via js. but changes not affect the existing element.

```php
<p id="termError" class="text-red-500" style="visibility:hidden">{{__("Bu alan zorunludur.")}}</p>
```

```js
.then(function(value) {myDisplayer(value);},
      function(error) {myDisplayer(error);});
```

```js
 function myDisplayer(value) {            
     if(value == true){
          alert("gh");
      }
     else{
          document.getElementById("termError").style.visibility = "visible";
          console.log(document.getElementById("termError"));
          }
        }
```

the element I display with console log is changed bu when I inspect, existing element is still hidden

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with that `id`?

Comment: Can you inspect the element and see if there's potentially any other CSS that causes the element to remain hidden?

Comment: Voting to close because the question does not include enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Lain this is the only one

Comment: @Fralle just style I show you